# Save only specific part from dropdown taken from AD query

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, active-directory

Currently working on user management page where there are name , username , email and level fields . All fields except for level are obtained from AD. I managed to make the values saved into database. However , the name field takes both username and email field instead. The dropdown would display the name but it saves username and email.

```
<th align="right" scope="row">Select User</th>
<td><script type="text/javascript">
var $ = function(e){ return document.getElementById(e); }
var swap = function(val){
var arr = val.split("|");
document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value = arr[0];
document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value = arr[1];
}
</script>

<select name="name" id="name" class="reginput" onchange="swap(this.value)"    />
<option value="">Select User</option>

<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name,Id FROM users");
$result = $this->Users_model->queryAD();

$options=$test;

//while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
for ($i=0; $i<$result["count"]; $i++) {
//$options .= '<option value="'.$row["name"].'">'.$row["name"].'  '.'</option>';

$options .= '<option value="'.$result[$i]["samaccountname"]  [0].'|'.$result[$i]["mail"][0].'">'.$result[$i]["displayname"][0].'   '.'</option>';



}

$options .= '</select>';


echo $options;
```

For example :

Select User : Jane Doe
Username    : Jane
Email       : janed@yahoo.com
Level       : Admin

User would be displayed as Jane | janed@yahoo.com instead of Jane Doe but other fields are fine.

[This is the page for inserting users , the display is fine but Full Name wont be saved properly into DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iE78.png)

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: @SandeshGupta it doesnt save the full name into database, takes the username and email instead.

Answer (score 0):

It takes the `username` and `email` instead of `Full name` because the `value` of the `option` you are giving is `$result[$i]["samaccountname"][0].'|'.$result[$i]["mail"][0]`

Change the value of the option to

```
$options .= '<option value="'.$result[$i]["displayname"][0].'">'.$result[$i]["displayname"][0].'   '.'</option>';
```

**EDIT**

To display username and email to user, and saving Fullname to DB, use this:

```
$options .= '<option value="'.$result[$i]["displayname"][0].'">"'.$result[$i]["samaccountname"]  [0].'|'.$result[$i]["mail"][0].'"</option>';
```

Comment: It saves the full name but the username and email wont be populated into their respective fields. Is it possible to put all the fields but only take the full name ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to save all the three fields into the database on selection of one select option?

Comment: I already have separate textbox fields for email and username. They work fine , inserting email and username values into database.